# Customize the Ownership email in a task list when assigned to a person SP2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-email

Is there an easy way to customize the generated emails that sends whenever i assign an item in a task list?

i need to remove the link that goes to the list and the one to modify the personal alerts...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your skills if it is easy.

You need to use `stsadm` and apply some XML templates

I forgot the further details.. last time I did this was BS (*Before StackOverflow*)

The long (*not mine*) explanation is at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx